# Match everything except a particular string

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to make a Regular expression which will include everything except a particular string.

eg:  in `pkg/linux-lts-xenial.html`

I want everything except `pkg/` and `.html`

Which will be, `linux-lts-xenial`

I will be using python for this. I have tried:

`[^pkg | .html | /]`

and even negative look ahead. I seem to be doing something wrong, though.

Would love if someone could point out, what.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to require these parts, but not include them in the match? Or are they optional?

Comment: Did you try `r"pkg/(.+)\.html"`?

Comment: Negative lookahead means that it only matches if it's *not* followed by the string.

Comment: Do you actually need a regex here? Is the use case always `dir/thing-I-care-about.html` ? Will the thing you care about always be left bound and right bound like this?

Comment: Your last attempt shows that you have a total misunderstanding of what `[...]` does. It doesn't match strings, it matches single characters.

Comment: @Barmar I am still learning and I do acknowledge what you said. I am trying to understand how to make it not match a string.

Comment: @DylanLawrence Yes it will always be.

Comment: *"I have tried:`[^pkg | .html | /]`"* - why? Are you saying that given a string starting `'pkg/` and ending with `'.html'` you want everything in between? What about strings that don't match the pattern? Could you give some more example inputs and outputs? Frankly `'pkg/linux-lts-xenial.html'[4:-5]` would do.

Comment: @DYZ Thanks that works.

Comment: @jonrsharpe String slicing could've been done. I wanted to try out regex. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Use positive lookarounds, not negative. Negative lookarounds only match when the string isn't surrounded by the lookarounds, but you want to match when they *are* surrounded by them, and just not include the lookarounds in the match.

```
(?<=pkg/).*(?=\.html)
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete anything before '/' and delete anything after '.', keep anything between those two (.*).

```
In[4]: s="pkg/linux-lts-xenial.html"
In[5]: re.sub(r'.*\/(.*)\..*',r'\1',s)
Out[5]: 'linux-lts-xenial'
```